Is there a way to fill in variables from tidycensus output?
I'm using the following code after loading in the tidycensus package:
mn_val_wide <- get_acs(year = 2022, geography = "county", table = "DP05", state = "MN", output = "wide", survey = "acs5")

This loads the data in a wide format, with the variable names being numbers and text and not being descriptive of what the variable contains. I'm wondering if there's a way to change the variable names to what the description of the variable is supposed to be.
There's a way to get the estimate and percent titles for the DP05 table by using the following code:
mn2022 <- load_variables(year = 2022, dataset = "acs5/profile", cache = TRUE)

Is there a way to use the mn2022 descriptions and somehow get them to be the column names for the mn_val_wide dataset? Or is there another way to get more descriptive variable names for the mn_val_wide dataset?

You can use the variables argument as documented here

I think a simple colnames() procedure will work, as long as the labels on the mn2022 file correspond with your mn_val_wide:
mycols<-unique(mn2022$label)
mycols

mycols2<-str_replace_all(mycols,"Estimate!!","Est_") # for easier reading
mycols2<-str_replace_all(mycols2,"Total Population!!","TotalPop_") # for easier reading


colnames(mn_val_wide)<-mycols2  # using the cleaner set of names

